# Que doit contenir notre FAQ ? What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-faq

As part of the [Take ownership of your community, The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) (7 EMQEB) I have began tagging question with [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). Those are subject that are important to new users and I think should be taken into account when building our FAQ.

Please take a review of those and criticize theses choices. At the end, the tag shall be a good summary of what is really important to new comers.

Furthermore, what should the [site FAQ](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq) contain?

---

Le site a deux FAQ : une première introduction sur la page [`faq`](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq) dont le lien se trouve en haut de toutes les pages, et des questions jugées importantes sur le site méta, indiquées par l'étiquette [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

J'ai commencé à étiquetter certaines questions avec [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). Merci de revoir et critiquer ces choix.

Et que doit contenir la [FAQ du site](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq) ?

Comment: Seems like @Gilles retaged all the question with [tag:faq-proposed] (See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1859344#1859344) even if my intends are really the selection of topics that should be included in the main site faq. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have done this and vanished offsite immediately. But I do think almost none of these were worthy of mention in the site FAQ. Anyway the [meta-tag:site-faq] tag is normally used on questions that discuss the site FAQ (like this one), not on questions that address matters worthy of the site FAQ. It would be more helpful if you made a list of the points you think should be covered in the site FAQ in an answer here (even better if you propose wording as well, but a list of points is a good start).

Comment: @Gilles yes ok. Let's do this.

Answer (score 7):

Pour contrer la logorrhée sèche de [ma première proposition](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/4th-emqeb-what-should-our-faq-contain/265#265), en voici une autre. Cette proposition a un contenu différent en français et en anglais, parce que les locuteurs des deux langues n'ont pas forcément les mêmes interrogations.

*Here is another proposal to counter the dry logorrhea in [my first proposal](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/4th-emqeb-what-should-our-faq-contain/265#265). This proposal has a different content in French and in English, because speakers of the two languages do not always have the same doubts.*

---

The French Language and Usage Stack Exchange site is for linguists, teachers, students, and anyone interested in the finer points of the French language. We welcome questions about French (including regional or dialectal variants) that meet the [general Stack Exchange guidelines](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

**Should I ask/answer in French or English?** Both languages are accepted. If you are learning French, we suggest that you learn by doing and ask in French, but there is no obligation. Note that some contributors prefer to answer in French, so you may get replies in French. On the [meta site](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/), we try to provide at least a summary of each post in both languages.

**What about translations?** We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than French. Asking about the meaning of a difficult French sentence is fine. So is asking how to express an idea in idiomatic French. But please don't ask us to translate a sentence to or from another language.

**What is the meaning of this word?** We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If your dictionaries have no entry for this word, or if the entry does not address your concerns, then please ask (and mention that you did check a dictionary and weren't satisfied with what you found).

---

### Quelles questions puis-je poser ici ?

Le site « French Language and Usage » sur Stack Exchange est destiné aux linguistes, aux enseignants, aux étudiants, et à toute personne qui s'intéresse de près à la langue française (y compris ses variations régionales ou dialectales).

**Quels types de questions sont admises ?** Ce site est [un site de questions-réponses](https://french.stackexchange.com/about), et pas un forum de discussions ouvertes. Merci d'éviter les questions qui ne font qu'ouvrir un débat ou auxquelles une réponse raisonnable couvrirait un livre entier. Pour ce qui est des questions subjectives, nous conseillons les [recommandations de MetaFilter](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter).

**Dois-je écrire en français ou en anglais ?** Les deux langues sont admises. Nous encourageons à répondre en anglais aux questions posées en anglais, pour donner une meilleure chance au demandeur de comprendre la réponse, mais ce n'est pas une obligation.

**Demandes de traduction.** Les demandes de traduction en tant que telles ne sont pas admises. Les questions telles que « comment exprimer idiomatiquement [idée] en français » ou les demandes d'explication d'une phrase en français sont bienvenues, mais les questions demandant une expertise certaine dans une langue étrangère sont hors sujet.

**J'ai une question sur le fonctionnement du site…** L'interface n'est pas encore disponible en français. Le [site méta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/) est destiné aux questions portant sur le fonctionnement du site. Merci de résumer vos messages francophones sur le site méta en anglais dans la mesure du possible. Vous pouvez également poser des questions sur le [salon de clavardage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage) (même s'il n'y a personne en ligne à la minute, quelqu'un finira probablement par arriver).

Comment: Semble bon à moi. Mais peut-être on peut dire "salon de chat (ou chien)"...

Comment: Je donne ma préférence pour clavardage.

Comment: « sur » le salon, pas « dans » ou « au » ? Je me demande aussi si pour les francophones il ne faudrait pas mettre un 'health warning' sur le fait qu'on est (pour l'heure) majoritairement descriptiviste...

Comment: Another suggestion: "Asking about the meaning of a difficult French sentence is fine" - please change this to "sentence **or expression**".

Answer (score 0):

Au vu de ce qui passe sur le site, et inspiré par la [FAQ du site sur l'anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq), voici un premier jet de proposition. C'est très verbeux, donc la question est plutôt quoi couper que quoi ajouter. Cette proposition concerne la partie que les modérateurs ♦ peuvent éditer, entre le titre « What kind of questions can I ask here? » et le paragraphe « Please look around … » au-dessus du deuxième titre « What kind of questions should I not ask here? ».

From what we've seen on the site so far, and inspired by the [English site FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq), here's a first proposal draft. This proposal is for the only part that ♦ moderators can edit, between the title “What kind of questions can I ask here?” and the paragraph “Please look around …” above the second title “What kind of questions should I not ask here?”.

---

*The French Language and Usage Stack Exchange site is for linguists, teachers, students, and anyone interested in the finer points of the French language. We welcome questions about:*

- usage, word choice, grammar, pronunciation;
- etymology and linguistic analysis;
- regional and dialectal differences;
- difficulties encountered by native speakers and foreign learners alike.

Some questions, while indirectly related to French, are out of scope for this site; please do not ask questions about these topics:

- translation requests: “how can I express [idea] in French?” is fine, so is “please explain [complicated sentence]”, but not “translate this sentence into [foreign language]” or “translate this sentence from [foreign language] into French”;
- languages other than French, including regional languages of France;
- definitions of a word or idiom: look in a dictionary first (but feel free to ask if the dictionary had no entry or the entry didn't have enough information).

### Quel type de questions puis-je poser ici ?

Le site « French Language and Usage » sur Stack Exchange est destiné aux linguistes, aux enseignants, aux étudiants, et à toute personne qui s'intéresse de près à la langue française. Nous accueillons les questions à propos :

- de l'usage, du choix de mots, de la grammaire, de la prononciation ;
- d'étymologie et d'analyse linguistique ;
- des différences régionales et dialectales ;
- des difficultés rencontrées tant par les locuteurs natifs que par les apprenants.

Certaines questions, bien qu'elles aient un rapport avec le français, sont hors sujet. Merci de ne pas poser de questions sur les sujets suivants :

- demandes de traduction : « comment exprimer [une idée] en français » est une question valable, tout comme « expliquer [une phrase compliquée] », mais pas « traduire cette phrase en/depuis le français » ;
- les langues autres que le français, même si ce sont des langues parlées dans certaines régions de France ;
- les définitions d'un mot ou d'un idiome : consulter d'abord un dictionnaire (maos si l'entrée du dictionnaire manque ou n'est pas claire, alors la question est intéressante et mérite d'être posée).

### Quelle est la langue du site ? What is the language of the site?

Le site rassemble des contributeurs francophones et non ou peu francophones. Les messages sont admis en français (la métalangue suivant la langue) ou en anglais (la langue de communication internationale). Nous encourageons les apprenants à poser leurs questions en français (c'est en faisant qu'on apprend) et les répondeurs à répondre dans la langue de la question (pour être sûr que le demandeur pourra comprendre la réponse), mais ce n'est pas une obligation.

Le [site méta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/) est destiné aux questions sur le fonctionnement du site. Pour que les discussions sur la bonne marche du site soient comprises de tous, il est demandé dans la mesure du possible que chaque message inclue une traduction au moins résumée dans l'autre langue (français ou anglais).

*The site has both participants who speak fluent French and participants who speak little or no French. Messages may be in French (the language being its own metalanguage) or in English (the international communication language). We encourage learners to write questions in French (learn by doing), and answerers to reply in the same language as the question (to be sure that the asker can understand the reply), but there is no obligation.*

The [meta site](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/) is for questions about the main site. In order for discussions about the running of the site to be understood by all, please include a translation of each post (or at least of a summary) into the other language (French or English).

Comment: La mention *anglais (la langue de communication internationale)* me semble discutable. Nous sommes ici **aussi** parce que nous aimons le français, (dont le recul sur le plan international est inquiétant à long terme, amha). Si nous admettons d'emblée cet état de fait (anglais langue de communication internationale) nous risquons de faire fuir des participants potentiels qui sont des défenseurs de la francophonie et qui auraient toute leur place sur FL&U.

Comment: the mention of  *English (the international communication language)* doesn't seem appropriate. People who come to FL&U are **also** here because they like French and a lot of those fight in defence of the French language. If we advertise *English (the international communication language)* from the start we might lose potential participants who might have been an asset to FL&U.

Comment: Par contre mentionner le fait que *Stackexchange* est un site anglophone et qu'il faut pouvoir se faire comprendre des créateurs et modérateurs globaux, et donc qu'il faut poster les messages aussi en anglais sur le site meta semble indispensable. Mais ne pas en faire une obligation car il ne faut pas refroidir ceux qui ne maitrisent pas l'anglais. On pourrait demander de signaler que la traduction est manquante (quelqu'un d'autre s'en chargera).

Comment: But it seems important to me to mention the fact that *Stackexchange* originates as an English speaking site and that in order to make oneself understood from creators and global moderators posts on meta should be in French  and in English. It mustn't sound as compulsory though, and we could add that as long as the OP mentions that the translation is lacking, someone from FL&U can take over for the translation.

Comment: Désolée pour ces quatre commentaires à la suite, j'ai hésité entre *réponse* et *commentaire*, une réponse à un wiki ne me semblait pas appropriée. Sorry for so many comments one after the answer, I suppose I could have handled it better but I didn't want to make it an answer.